# Acceder a subnivel en mongo

Tags: python, pymongo

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Python y estoy guardando los datos y accediendo a una base de datos mongo que he creado.
Tengo un problema en una colección de parámetros, en la que guardo en un documento los parámetros posibles de esta forma:

[mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHlVs.jpg)

{
    "nacionalidad" : {
        "España" : "ES",
        "Portugal": "PT"
    }
    "XXXX":{
     }
}

He creado un API rest en la que recibo un json, entre los que están los campos que quiero validar en este documento, pero no lo consigo... 
Si estuviese en el primer nivel entiendo que sería así:
if parametros.count_documents({'nacionalidad': content['nacionalidad']})>0:

Pero, cómo lo busco en un segundo nivel? 
Por cierto, para validar si existe estoy haciendo el count documents, pero no sé si es más apropiado hacer un find o un find_one...

Gracias

Comment: Puedes proporcionarnos más información, un fragmento del código. Seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: El campo con el que quiero buscar la información lo tengo en el content, es este: content['nationality']. Con este campo, que me puede venir las siglas del país (ES, PT, FR, etc), quiero comprobarlo si existe en mongo (arriba puedes ver cómo lo he creado).
He intentado todo esto:
param.count_documents({['nacionalidad']['pais']: content['nationality']}, limit=1) == 0:
param.find_one({content['nationality']['nacionalidad']['pais']}, lim)}")
elif f"{param.find_one({content['nationality']})['nacionalidad']['pais']}"
elif param.count_documents({('nacionalidad','pais'): content['nationality']})

Comment: Y si tratas de cambiar el esquema de los datos, ejemplo: `{"nacionalidad": [{"name": "Españá","acronym":"ES"}]'}`. De esta forma seria mas facil de hacer la consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Conseguido.

> Al final había que poner el subnivel seguido del nombre separado por un punto:

```
param.count({'nacionalidad.pais': {'$in': [content['nationality']]}}))
```

Comment: No olvides por favor cuando te sea posible marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, si fue la solución al problema

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución.

Mi esquema:

```
{
  ... ,
  nationality: [{
     name: 'string',
     acronym: 'string'
  }]
}
```

La consulta:

```
db.[collection_name].count({
  nationality: {
     $elemMatch: {
        name: 'España', acronym: 'ES'}
     }
  }
})
```

Suerte, espero que sea de ayuda.